# Get all values of some fields in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I have objects like this:

```
{
    model:"Samsung Galaxy Note 8",
    cpu : "Snapdragon 835 Exynos 8895",
    storage: "64/128/256 GB",
    removable:"256GB microSDXC",
    ram: "6 GB",
    os: "Android 7.1.1 'Nougat'",
    size:{
        l:162.5,
        h:74.8,
        w:8.6
    },
    weight:195,
    battery:"3300 mAh Li-Ion, non-removable battery",
    display:"6.3', 2960x1440",
    camera:{
        rear:12,
        front:8
    },
    image:"https://image.com"
}
```

I want for example all the distinct values of cpus and rams. If I use distinct() mongodb function, i can get only all the values of one field, but if I want multiple fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation. Like below and it will give you all the different combinations of cpu and ram:

```
db.datastorevalues.aggregate(
    [

        {
            $group: {
                _id:{
                     "cpu ":"$cpu ",
                     "ram":"$cpu "
                }
            }
        }
    ]

);
```

## edit

If you want all the distinct values for the cpus and all the distinct values for the rams in the database

```
db.datastorevalues.aggregate(
    [

        {
            $group: {
                _id: null,
                cpus: {$addToSet: "$cpu"},
                rams: {$addToSet: "$ram"},

            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: ok, but I don't want couples (ram,cpu), I want all the distinct values for the cpus and all the distinct values for the rams in the database

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). Aggregation pipeline has a lot of useful methods.

Aggregate query to group and find distinct values on cpus and ram is

```
db.so.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{ram:"$ram", cpu:"$cpu"}}}])
```

Comment: Use two aggregate queries one for cpu and one for ram, since using group by for two different values to be distinct in a single aggregate query is not possible. If this is your case then you can go with two distinct queries itself and no need of aggregation.